# Something about regular expression

Tags: regex

If I want to get the current price `416.00` of the following content, what regexp I can use to get it? There are some places in the webpage with similar content, except the one I want has the word `Discount` in a few lines after the current price. `416,520` and `20%` are variable. Thanks.

```
<tr> 
    <td class="txt_11px_b_EB6495" width="50" nowrap>Current Price?</td>
    <td class="txt_11px_b_EB6495">HK$ 416.00</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td class="txt_11px_n_999999">Original price?</td>
    <td class="txt_11px_n_999999">HK$ 520.00</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td class="txt_9px_n_999999">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="txt_9px_n_999999">Discount 20%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
" (\d+\.\d*)</td>"
```

That will match 520.00, 2.00, 123.1, and 123.

Comment: I think this corrected version would do just fine. `(\d+\.\d*)`

Comment: In fact there are still other current prices information in the webpage, the one I want to capture is the one with "Discount" after the 11th line of html code. Therefore, if just use the (\d+\.\d$) will get other current prices

Answer (score 0):

Use a HTML parser to get the text node, then extract the price using a regex.

You would use something like...

```
\d+(?:\.\d{2}|%)
```

I just tested it and it matched...

- 416.00
- 520.00
- 20%

I assumed (it was unclear to me) you want the prices *and* the percentage discount. I also matched the `%` so you can tell what are the percentages in the matches.